# Unable to Open TOR

Tags: networking, tor

I have downloaded tor browser and also I have installed the same in my office PC. When I click on connect to tor network, It keeps connecting for some time and automatically will get closed after giving a pop up, "Tor connecting time out" and it will be closed.. I tried more than 10 times by doing the same.. Can you please suggest me how do I open tor in my PC? ..

Comment: You are probably behind some kind of firewall at the office. Using Tor most likely breaches security in the office, and therefore your ICT department has most likely blocked it.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tor.stackexchange.com. Tor related questions are discussed there. In your case Tor is probably blocked and you should use bridges to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to set some custom bridges. Search for bridges that works in your country. Then open the torrc file and add the following code:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge ip.ad.dr.ess:port abcd1234hash
Bridge ip.ad.dr.ess:port abcd1234hash
Bridge ip.ad.dr.ess:port abcd1234hash
```

[This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjTl_eto4rHAhXHORQKHaATACY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.torproject.org%2Fdocs%2Fbridges.html.en&ei=evy9VdPyBMfzUKCngLAC&usg=AFQjCNH64Vo73NxbxQXNFes9nn42tsOUsQ&sig2=tG5J1iA-Pz_x19TDSe7M9A) is how to find new bridges and [this one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/cant-connect-tor-network-failed-to-establish-network/4920#4920) is how to add them.